# Is there a contract expiry column on the team squad page?

Tags: football-manager-2018

For various reasons I would like to check the contract expiry dates on the team squad pages:

[image: Team squad page]

It is possible to add and remove columns, but the available options in the contract sub-menu does not include contract expiry, or am I just blind?

[image: Contract sub-menu]

I am 99% certain that this was possible in previous versions of Football Manager.

Is there any way to add the contract expiry column? Is it perhaps in another sub-menu?

Answer (score 1):

If you click the *General Info* dropdown menu at the top left of your first screenshot, you should have a *Contract* option such as in the screenshot below:

[image]

You can see that now one of the columns on the right shows the expiry date. It's also quite useful for when the renewal time comes.

Comment: That is true, for my own squad page. However, I cannot find that option on other squad pages.